# Java Small Map<String, List> vs Large Map<Object, String> performance

Tags: java, performance, list, dictionary

I have a list of distinct objects, like such:

```
Object1
Object2
...
ObjectN
```

Each object has a `TYPE`, which can be have one of several values ( no more than 10 ). This means there are a lot of objects having the same type.

These objects will be mapped with regard to the type.
Which method would be more effective in terms of speed?
Having a `TreeMap<TYPE, List<Object>>` or having a `TreeMap<Object, TYPE>`.
The map used will not be a `HashMap`, but a `TreeMap`, the reason is beyond the purpose of this question.

If i used a `HashMap`, i believe it would be faster to implement a `Map<Object, String>` due to the `O(1)` access time of the `Object`.However, I cannot tell if I use a `TreeMap` which method would offer the better performance.

As a notice, the number of **Objects** is not in a known interval and cannot be approximated.

**EDIT**: Implementation depends on this choice. I can either take all elements having a certain type and make my computations or take all elements, get their type and then compute my data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how do you want to read the data?

Comment: it will be a stream of elements.

Comment: sorry i mean you save `objs` to `Map<>`, and then how do you read the `objs`

Comment: yes, after saving them i have to make further computations on them

Comment: Make `TYPE` to an `enum` (and name it properly as `Type` :D) and you can use an `EnumMap`, which is basically an array indexed by `ordinal()`. If this is possible, it's surely the fastest way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TreeMap is implemented as a red-black tree inside, so its time-complexity will be O(logn) for any operations. So HashMap is faster for the index access. But with the HashMap you cant store your data in ordered way, so search operations will be O(n). From docs:

> A Red-Black tree based NavigableMap implementation. The map is sorted
>   according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator
>   provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used.
>   This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the
>   containsKey, get, put and remove operations.

There is no difference if you use `TreeMap<TYPE, List<Object>>` or  `TreeMap<Object, TYPE>`. The difference in performance depends on the implementation of your equals and hashcode functions. Not on the choice of the Mapping strategy in this case. Choose the way, which is most appropriate for your software design needs.

Comment: is this assuming that the `List` is the key of the Map. In my question, either the Type of the object or the object is the key. Or i did not get your answer right.

Comment: I think I misunderstood you, but is Object in the TreeMap a List??

Comment: But you specify it here: "TreeMap<TYPE, List<Object>> or having a TreeMap<Object, TYPE>". So in the second example is it just one of the instances from the first Map?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea.

Comment: Can 2 objects have the same type?

Comment: a lot of objects share the same type. As an example, in my tests, there are 400 objects having only 3 types.

Comment: what about the speed of data access? That is where the main difference in performance may occur.

Comment: For the Treemap it will be logn as I mentioned, so if you substitute it for HashMap, it will be O(1). But otherwise, it does not matter, if your Type is the key, or your Object is (as long as it is not List), the value retrieval will be at the same speed for your 2 options of mapping in the TreeMap.

Comment: But if you need to process the List afterwards, and you are not going to use index access, but ie. search, then it is wiser to store it as TreeMap<Object, Type>. but it is already software design - I dont know what you are going to do with the List after retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

All of you implementation needs to get all elements

**take all elements having a certain type and make my computations or**

obviously, `Map<Type, List>` is better in this condition .

**take all elements, get their type and then compute my data.**

this is equals to

```
 foreach types do
      do condition (1)
```

So, `Map<Type, List>` is better